# Swift filter array of objects

Tags: swift

```
class book{
    var nameOfBook: String!
}

var englishBooks=[book(),book(),book()]
var arr = englishBooks.filter {
    contains($0.nameOfBook, "rt")
}
```

I'm using this filter but with error cannot invoke filter with an argument

Answer (score 51):

`contains()` checks if a sequence contains a given element, e.g.
if a `String` contains a given `Character`.

If your intention is to find all books where the name contains the *substring* "rt", then you can use `rangeOfString()`:

```
var arr = englishBooks.filter {
    $0.nameOfBook.rangeOfString("rt") != nil
}
```

or for case-insensitive comparison:

```
var arr = englishBooks.filter {
    $0.nameOfBook.rangeOfString("rt", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}
```

As of **Swift 2,** you can use

```
nameOfBook.containsString("rt") // or
nameOfBook.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("rt")
```

and in **Swift 3** this is

```
nameOfBook.contains("rt") // or
nameOfBook.localizedStandardContains("rt") // or
nameOfBook.range(of: "rt", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
```

Answer (score 17):

Sorry this is an old thread. Change you code slightly to properly init your variable 'nameOfBook'.

```
class book{
   var nameOfBook: String!
   init(name: String) {
      nameOfBook = name
   }
}
```

Then we can create an array of books.

```
var englishBooks = [book(name: "Big Nose"), book(name: "English Future 
Prime Minister"), book(name: "Phenomenon")]
```

The array's 'filter' function takes one argument and some logics, 'contains' function can take a simplest form of a string you are searching for.

```
let list1 = englishBooks.filter { (name) -> Bool in
   name.contains("English")
}
```

You can then print out list1 like so:

```
let list2 = arr1.map({ (book) -> String in
   return book.nameOfBook
})
print(list2)

// print ["English Future Prime Minister"]
```

Above two snippets can be written short hand like so:

```
let list3 = englishBooks.filter{ ($0.nameOfBook.contains("English")) }
print(list3.map({"\($0.nameOfBook!)"}))
```

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT 4.0**

In order to filter objects and get resultant array you can use this

```
self.resultArray = self.upcomingAuctions.filter {
                    $0.auctionStatus == "waiting"
                }
```

Answer (score 6):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

```
public filterStr = ""

public var books: [Book] = []

public var booksFiltered: [Book] {
   get {
      filterStr.isEmpty
         ? books
         : books.filter { $0.alias.range(of: filterStr, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in case you want to delete an interval of object which has specific IDs (matchIDsToDelete) from an array of object (matches)

```
var matches = [Match]
var matchIDsToDelete = [String]
matches = matches.filter { !matchIDsToDelete.contains($0.matchID) }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more useful for lack of wrong typing situation.

```
englishBooks.filter( { $0.nameOfBook.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2** use the `remove(where:)` functionality. `filter` [isn't doing well with memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0197-remove-where.md), `remove(where:)` does the job better.

To do what you want:

```
englishBooks.removeAll { !$0.nameOfBook.contains("English") }
```

Comment: case-sensitive(!)