# How can I find a specific item from custom object in a huge array - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

How can I find a specific item from custom object in a huge array like bellow?

```
struct ResponseCourseTypeFilter {
    var returnCourseTypeFilter: [[String : String]]
}

struct ViewModelCourseTypeFilter {
    struct DisplayedCourseTypeFilter {
        var titlesCourseType: String
        var isSelectedType: Bool
    }
    var displayedCourseTypeFilter: [DisplayedCourseTypeFilter]
}
```

I need to get values `titlesCourseType` are `true`.

My `array` is huge.

Comment: Do you need to filter an array of type `CourseTypeFilter`

Comment: I can't find the array example, but I guess your array is an array of `CourseTypeFilter`. `array.first(where: { $0. isSelectedType == true })` this is if you need only one item, and `array.filter { $0. isSelectedType == true }` for all of them. [Google magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673936/swift-filter-array-of-objects)

Comment: @ Sh_Khan. I need to get values titlesCourseType are true.

Comment: `titlesCourseType` is a string, did you mean the property `isSelectedType`? And do you want to filter the array `displayedCourseTypeFilter` or some other array?

Comment: How huge is your `array`, thousands , or millions?

Comment: If the `array`, why keeps it in memory, why not use Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suppose the `ViewModelCourseTypeFilter` instance is like,

```
let viewModel = ViewModelCourseTypeFilter(displayedCourseTypeFilter: [
    DisplayedCourseTypeFilter(titlesCourseType: "First", isSelectedType: true),
    DisplayedCourseTypeFilter(titlesCourseType: "Second", isSelectedType: false),
    DisplayedCourseTypeFilter(titlesCourseType: "Third", isSelectedType: true)
])
```

Then you can get all `titlesCourseType` values where `isSelectedType = true` like so,

```
let arr = viewModel.displayedCourseTypeFilter.compactMap({ $0.isSelectedType ? $0.titlesCourseType : nil })
print(arr) //["First", "Third"]
```

Comment: @ PGDev. Is it work for huge arrays? for example 10000 items.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
let arr = viewModel.displayedCourseTypeFilter.filter { $0.isSelectedType }
```

better?

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I am trying to do better.