# Filter an Array of Structs by Months? SwiftUI

Tags: swift

Hey guys I got something very similar going on in my project. But I was wondering when you have an array of structs, how would you be able to filter for items in specific month? Also the date is in epoch form.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestStruct {
    var food: String
    var date: Double
    
}

class Test: ObservableObject{
    
    
    let food1 = TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794)
    
    
    let food2 = TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794)
    
    
    let food3 = TestStruct(food: "icecream", date: 1652204394)
    
    
    let foodForYear: [TestStruct] = [food1, food2, food3]
    
}
```

Comment: To filter for months you have to convert the epoch date somewhere to `Date` with `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`

Comment: once you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862096/filter-array-of-tuples-in-swift and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673936/swift-filter-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a simple `filter` on the array, and getting the `TimeInterval` you need in order to do the filter, here is a simple example:

```
       import Foundation


    struct TestStruct {
        var food: String
        var date: Double
        
        var parsedDate: Date {
            Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
        }
        
        var monthNumber: Int {
            Calendar.current.component(.month, from: parsedDate)
        }
    }

    class Test: ObservableObject{
        
        let food1 = TestStruct(food: "Hamburger", date: 1641058794)
        let food2 = TestStruct(food: "HotDog", date: 1651426794)
        let food3 = TestStruct(food: "icecream", date: 1652204394)
        
        let foodForYear: [TestStruct] = [food1, food2, food3]
        
        func filterMonthy() {
            let fiteredByMonths = foodForYear.filter({$0.monthNumber == 1}) // any logic you want to apply
            print(fiteredByMonths)
        }
    }
```

Take a look at the documentation: [Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using epoch form itself instead of native Date:

```
struct TestStruct {
  var food: String
  var date: Date

  init(food: String, date: Double) {
   self.food = food
   self.date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
  }
}
```

In this case you can easy get month or year in a string format:

```
extension TestStruct {
  var monthName: String {
     return date.formatted(
           Date.FormatStyle()
           .year(.defaultDigits) // remove if you don't need it
           .month(.abbreviated) // you can choose .wide if you want other format or read help for more information
     )
  }
}
```

Now let's check it:

```
let foodForYear: [TestStruct] = ...
print(foodForYear.sorted{ $0.monthName > $1.monthName}) // sorting
let nameOfMonth = "SomeMonthName" // depends from your format style 
print(foodForYear
    .compactMap{
         if $0.monthName.contains(nameOfMonth) {
             return $0
         } else { return nil }
    }
)
```